# Draw chemical laboratory equipment

Tags: latex, tikz

I need to draw some chemical laboratory equiment setups.  It will include Erlenmeyer flask, Bunsen burner and so on.

Does TikZ provide support for such drawings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw pretty much anything you want: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/

But it doesn't look like TikZ includes premade versions of lab equipment.

---

I'd try asking your question over at https://tex.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called `pst-labo` ([CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-labo)) which uses PSTricks for drawing. But for something rather complex I would use vector images or [CAD-blocks of chemical equipment](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34367/where-can-i-find-cad-blocks-for-lab-glassware). I'm pretty sure it's going to save a lot of time.

Comment: You've read the link in the answer, haven't you? The question is discussed there including PSTricks. Thanks for the feedback anyway.

Comment: @harper Probably, I actually stumbled upon similar question on Chem.SE and decided to have a look around.